# Работа с массивом float в clickhouse

Tags: sql, массивы, float, clickhouse

Как в Clickhouse сгенерировать массив значений типа **Float32** с заданными началом, концом и шагом, подобно тому, как это делает функция **range()** для целых чисел?

Comment: такого функционала нет, есть `generateRandom` для генерации случаных данных таблицей, по задданым шаблонам, а для реализации того что вы хотите надо писать скрипт для генерации нужных данных и вставлять в БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать это так:

```sql
WITH
    0.3 AS start,
    0.4 AS step,
    5 AS iterations,
    arrayWithConstant(iterations, 0) AS zeroArray,
    arrayCumSum((x, index) -> if(index = 1, start, step), zeroArray, arrayEnumerate(zeroArray)) AS range
SELECT range

/*
┌─range─────────────────┐
│ [0.3,0.7,1.1,1.5,1.9] │
└───────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо!